# Ubuntu 10.04: put computer to sleep when inactive for 4 hours

Tags: ubuntu, power-management

Under the power management tab, I have the option to put the computer to sleep when inactive for 10 minutes, 30 minutes, 1 hour or 2 hours.  Is there a configuration file I can edit to add 4 hours to that menu?

Thanks,

SetJmp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tested it, but it should be possible to do it with gconf-editor program. Start it and search (keyboard shortcut Ctrl-F) for sleep_computer_ac key and set its value to 14400 seconds.

Comment: I upvoted because this works, but I hope someone will come up with a method that inserts the value into the menu.  Using this method, the menu does not indicate what the actual setting is (it appears blank).  Thanks for your help... it makes a difference!

Comment: @SetJmp: the plank value for the actual settings sound like a bug to me. Perhaps you could submit a bug report about it: http://projects.gnome.org/gnome-power-manager/bugs.html